# Conjunto de strings para um for loop usando pipe (shell script)

Tags: bash, shell-script

Estou tentando escrever um shell script que processe umas strings e passe todas elas por pipe para um for loop, porém estou com problemas para fazer o iterador passar por essas strings, pois achei que se usasse o $* daria certo. O objetivo é conseguir criar varias subpastas com o nome de cada string.

```
for i in $(seq 1 30); do 
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 0-9 | head -c 8 ; echo ;
done | 
sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{5\}\)/\1-\2/' | 
tr '\n' ' ' | for folder in $*; do mkdir diretorio/$folder ; done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar um arquivo temporário para isso.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMP_FILE=/tmp/tabela

for i in $(seq 1 30); do
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 0-9 | head -c 8 ; echo ;
done |
    sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{5\}\)/\1-\2/'  > $TEMP_FILE

IFS='
'
for LINE in $(cat $TEMP_FILE)
do
        mkdir diretorio/$LINE
done
```

Utilizando xargs, é possivel fazer diretamente

```
#!/bin/bash
cd diretorio
for i in $(seq 1 30); do
    cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd 0-9 | head -c 8 ; echo ;
done |
    sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)\([[:digit:]]\{5\}\)/\1-\2/'  | xargs -L1 mkdir
```

Comment: Foi meio que a solução que acabou me restando, porém achava que haveria alguma forma mais direta